# How to display st_atime and st_mtime

Tags: c, linux

I want to display my two attributes from the structure stat

```
struct stat {
dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
```

};

Here is my code that i try to display the last time access and the last time of last modification of folder/file

```
struct tm *time;
char buffer[200];
time = localtime(file_info.st_atime);
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", time);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
time = localtime(file_info.st_mtime);
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", time);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

I want to display like human readble time and date like 15.03.1952 23:11:34 of a folder/file info that has been last modifed or access in linux

Comment: Did you mean to use %s instead of s in the printf statements?

Comment: yes, sorry for missing the % on the s, yea in there i want to display as a string from the buffer

Comment: @Hoenir So what's not working for you with the current code ? Any compiler errors ? Any output ? Is the output not as expected ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This deviates a bit from your code in terms of style, but perhaps it's helpful?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* formatdate(char* str, time_t val)
{
        strftime(str, 36, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime(&val));
        return str;
}

int main()
{
    int errno;
    const char* filename;
    filename = "stat.c";

    errno = 0;
    struct stat *file_info = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
    if (lstat(filename, file_info) != 0) {
            perror("Error");
            exit(1);
    }

    char date[36];
    printf("Access: %s\n", formatdate(date, file_info->st_atime));
    printf("Modify: %s\n", formatdate(date, file_info->st_mtime));
    printf("Change: %s\n", formatdate(date, file_info->st_ctime));
    free(file_info);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i don't quite get it why you used pointers you  complicate things so much with that pointers and yeah you probably right way ahead of my style of coding, thanks for the response i still wait for a better answer

Answer (score 0):

```
        char buffer[200];

    printf("Access : %s\n", formatdate(buffer, file_info.st_atime));
    printf("Modify : %s\n", formatdate(buffer, file_info.st_mtime));
    printf("\n\n");




char *formatdate(char *buff, time_t val)
{
    strftime(buff,200, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime(&val));
    return buff;
}
```

And this is the answer that i was looking for thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `printf("%s", asctime(localtime(&buffer.st_mtime)));`